# find names HAVING multiple account numbers

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE one_many
  (name VARCHAR2(20),
  acc_num VARCHAR2(20))

  INSERT ALL 
  INTO one_many VALUES ('abc','a-110')
  INTO one_many VALUES ('def','b-256')
  INTO one_many VALUES ('xyz','v-586')
  INTO one_many VALUES ('uij','o-451')
  INTO one_many VALUES ('pqr','')
  INTO one_many VALUES ('abc','a-120')
  INTO one_many VALUES ('xyz','v-588')
  SELECT * FROM dual;
```

how to find one-many cases i.e. SELECT those name HAVING mulitple acc_num??

```
Desired o/p:
NAME ACC_NUM
abc  a-110  
abc  a-120  
xyz  v-586  
xyz  v-588
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` in this case.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM one_many
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link (*two queries included*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75dce/3)

or

Maybe this is what you mean.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM one_many a
     INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT name, COUNT(*) totalCount
        FROM one_many
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) b ON a.name = b.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75dce/11)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but I also need to show the multiple acc_name.

Comment: what do you mean multiple account name?

Answer (score 1):

This query seems designed for the analytic functions:

```
select name, acc_num
from (select om.*,
             count(*) over (partition by name) as NumOnAccount
      from one_many om
     ) t
where NumOnAccount > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

u can do like this

```
      SELECT * FROM one_many
       WHERE acc_num IN 
                     (SELECT acc_num FROM 
                                     one_many
                                      GROUP BY name ,acc_num 
                                       HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                      );
```